# Can I create this layout in a flex container? The order is very important (I plan to swap elements in the future)

Tags: html, css, flexbox

[Here's a sample plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMNPK.jpg)

```
<div class="flex">
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
    <div class="item">4</div>
</div>
```

I need to line up the elements as in the picture, but not wrap the 1st and 2nd blocks in another additional div. Is this possible? I need this so that I can easily change the order of the elements later via the 'order' CSS property.

I cannot find a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using CSS Grid for this job:

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="div1">1</div>
  <div class="div2">2</div>
  <div class="div3">3</div>
  <div class="div4">4</div>
</div>
```

```css
.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 5px;
  grid-row-gap: 5px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
}

.div1, .div2, .div3, .div4 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
}

.div1 { grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2; }
.div2 { grid-area: 2 / 1 / 3 / 2; }
.div3 { grid-area: 1 / 2 / 3 / 4; }
.div4 { grid-area: 1 / 4 / 3 / 6; }
```

---

### Edit

Based on comment, here is a solution for using flexbox. I am not sure how it will perform on smaller screens (I believe that a scrollbar will just appear), but can try this approach using `inline-flex`.
Change the CSS variables to change the size of the unit grid as well as the gap between the boxes.

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="div1">1</div>
  <div class="div2">2</div>
  <div class="div3">3</div>
  <div class="div4">4</div>
</div>
```

```css
:root {
  --gap: 5px;
  --unitSize: 100px;
}

.parent {
  display: inline-flex;
  width: calc(var(--unitSize) * 5);
  height: calc(var(--unitSize) * 2 + var(--gap) * 2);
  gap: var(--gap);
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.div1, .div2, .div3, .div4 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.div1, .div2 { 
  width: var(--unitSize); 
  height: calc(var(--unitSize) + var(--gap) / 2); 
}
.div3, .div4 { 
  width: calc(var(--unitSize) * 2); 
  height: calc(var(--unitSize) * 2 + var(--gap) * 2); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! The thing is, I can't use 'grid' for many reasons. I easily solve this problem by using wrap over elements 1 and 2, but then I can't change the order :(

Comment: Flexbox is maybe possible but it's really unnecessarily complicated because flex is mainly good for content that flows in one direction. Your content is going one position down 1 → 2 and then horizontal 3 → 4. 

Why can't you use grid ?

Comment: I do agree with @retober but to answer your question see the edited post. Try to stick to grid for this sort of thing as flexbox is not really designed to do this.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much again! I'll try to use the 'grid' tomorrow. Because I can see that it won't work without crutches. Thank you infinitely.